# zoomstart, but no zoomend event fired on pinch zoom

Tags: leaflet

I need to detect the zoomend on a pinch zoom with `leaflet v1.0.0.rc3`. In rear cases the `zoomend` event ist not fired.

Anybody else got those problems? How to solve this?

Currently testing an old android with a chromium web view, 3D enabled.

```
...

map.on('zoomstart', function(e){
    console.log("zoomstart");
    //hide some layers...
});

map.on('zoomend', function(e){
    console.log("zoomend: " + map.getZoom());
    //show some layers again...
});

...
```

Comment: Is your issue reproducible with previous versions of Leaflet? If you can reproduce on [Leaflet Playground](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/), possibly using the [prosthetic-hand](https://github.com/Leaflet/prosthetic-hand) (and of course you will need to specify exactly your android and chromium versions), then it would probably be a valid bug to report into Leaflet [issues tracker](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues)

Comment: @ghybs ty! but i will test other devices first an will try to isolate the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a leaflet bug. Please try to isolate the issue (which devices, browsers, etc; also whether you're dragging out of the edge of the webview/touchscreen or not) and report it at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues